# Is there a way to change the MONGO_URL in code?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I'm searching for a way to change the way Meteor loads the Mongo database. Right now, I know I can set an environment variable when I launch Meteor (or export it), but I was hoping there was a way to do this in code. This way, I could dynamically connect to different instances based on conditions.

An example test case would be for the code to parse the url 'testxx.site.com' and then look up a URL based on the 'textxx' subdomain and then connect to that particular instance.

I've tried setting the process.env.MONGO_URL in the server code, but when things execute on the client, it's not picking up the new values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just trying to bump this up - still trying to figure things out with no luck.

Comment: have you tried bundling the app and then running directly in node.js? this would allow you to use MONGO_URL: http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying

Answer (score 0):

Meteor connects to Mongo right when it starts (using [this code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js)), so any changes to `process.env.MONGO_URL` won't affect the database connection.

It sounds like you are trying to run one Meteor server on several domains and have it connect to several databases at the same time depending on the client's request. This might be possible with traditional server-side scripting languages, but it's not possible with Meteor because the server and database are pretty tightly tied together, and the server basically attaches to one main database when it starts up.

The *.meteor.com hosting is doing something similar to this right now, and in the future Meteor's Galaxy commercial product will allow you to do this - all by starting up separate Meteor servers per subdomain.